# Akka for Asynchronous processing?

Tags: java, scala, asynchronous, akka, nonblocking

My use case is there will be four microservices A,B,C and D. My input request to Microservice D will be generated based on the outputs from A,B and C.Since A,B,C are independent, Instead of synchronously calling A,B and C thereby blocking the thread and building the request for microservice 'D' after three calls, have planned to call it asynchronously. 
Is Akka a good fit for this use case? or it is overkill. 
I read that akka is a concurreny tool kit, since my application does not have concurrency concerns, still can i use akka just for asynchrous processing? or is it overkill?

Comment: What do you mean by "the output from A, B, C"? What kind of "output" do these services generated? How is this done?

Comment: Thanks @Lutz Horn for the comment.  A,B, C are three microservice. From microservice A based on the input request , will fetch config data from database and similarly will fetch the configurations for microservices b and C from their respective databases. Then after getting the configurations will build a json and then will feed it as input to microservice D.

Comment: So is there only one microservice (A?) making a single call to D with the complete JSON? This can be a simple REST call, why do you want to make it async?

Comment: Since there can be a maximum of 2000 request/sec . Instead of blocking the thread while microservices A,B, C get their config  and build the JSON for Microservice D, from their respective databases, hence prefer to do it async..

Comment: Microservices should have well defined and open interfaces. If you use Akka to communicate across microservices the microservices won't be able to be accessed by anything other than Akka. And they will be tightly coupled with each other by their Akka versions and message types.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definitely an overkill. If you don't want to block a thread when calling another service all you need is a non-blocking http client. Or even a blocking http client that works on a separate thread pool. Just use anything that returns you `Future[ResponseFromService]`. `akka-http` client is one of options. But not raw akka.

Comment: Agree that this is fairly straight forward to do in high level akka-http. Most of my microservices are written in akka-http using the route dsl, but only one is uses akka and actors. (I would only use actors where I need the concurrency and I cannot think of an easier way to do it).